# Empty check in condition is being bypassed and running

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a form where users can attach a file and send. I am noticing when users submit the form without an attachment that this condition is still running:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']) && $_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'] != 4)
```

I cannot figure out why it would be running through since the filename would be empty.

Does anyone have any idea why the condition is still running?

```
   if ($_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'] == 1) {
        $error = "The file {$_POST['first_name']} attempted to upload is too large. Contact them for an alternate way to send this file.";
        $template = str_replace("{filename}", "$error", $template);
    }
    if (!empty($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']) && $_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'] != 4) {
        $fu = new fileUpload();
        $filename = $fu->upload();
        $out = (count($filename) > 1 ? 'Multiple files were' : 'A file was'). '  uploaded. You can download ' . (count($filename) > 1 ? 'them' : 'the file'). ' from:</ul>';
        foreach ($filename as $indFile) {
             $out .= "<li><a href='/uploads/{$indFile}'>{$indFile}</a></li>";
        }
        $out .= '</ul>';
        $template = str_replace("{filename}", $out, $template);
        clearstatcache();
    } else {
        $template = str_replace("{filename}", "", $template);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadedFile[]" id="uploadedFileTest" multiple>
<button type="submit">
```

UPDATE - results of var_dump($_FILES):

```
array(1) { 
  ["uploadedFile"]=> array(5) { 
     ["name"]=> array(1) { 
       [0]=> string(0) "" 
     } 
     ["type"]=> array(1) { 
       [0]=> string(0) "" 
     } 
     ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { 
       [0]=> string(0) "" 
     } 
     ["error"]=> array(1) { 
       [0]=> int(4) 
     } 
     ["size"]=> array(1) { 
       [0]=> int(0) 
     } 
   } 
}
```

New Code:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
        foreach($file['name'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == "") { //empty string
                if($file['error'][$key] != 4) { //error code is not #4
                    //do your code here, I did not check your other code


                    echo "name is empty AND error is NOT 4";
                } else { //error code IS #4
                    echo "error code is 4";
                }
            } else {
                echo "name is NOT empty!";

                $fu = new fileUpload();
                    $filename = $fu->upload();
                    $out = (count($filename) > 1 ? 'Multiple files were' : 'A file was'). '  uploaded. You can download ' . (count($filename) > 1 ? 'them' : 'the file'). ' from:</ul>';
                    foreach ($filename as $indFile) {
                         $out .= "<li><a href='uploads/{$indFile}'>{$indFile}</a></li>";
                    }
                    $out .= '</ul>';
                    $template = str_replace("{filename}", $out, $template);
            }
        }
    }
    clearstatcache();
```

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump($_FILES);` when submitting without a file to check what it actually contains?

Comment: You can put it before the if-statement. It doesn't really matter since you say that the if-statement always evaluates as true.

Comment: The problem is that you're checking it as if you only get one file, while you're form is set up for multiple files. You check if `['uploadedFile']['name']` is empty, which it isn't. It contains an non empty array.

Comment: Well there you go it contains nonempty Array. So it Is not Empty itself...

Comment: Remove the [] from the input name

Comment: Is there another solution that doesn't involve changing how I submit the file? It took me forever to get this working and I don't know how else to get more than one file without the `[]` in the name. Something that pertains only to this isolated condition that I can check for?

Comment: @slepic - If you look at the rest of the code, you can see that they _do_ want to be able to upload multiple files so that is not a solution.

Comment: Well sure, check emptiness of the right thing. You have vardumped it So you Now know the true structure And where the Empty name really resides...

Comment: Keep your HTML as it is. It's correct. Have a look [at the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) about uploading multiple files (look at the user comments as well) and you'll get a clearer picture of what happens. You basically need to iterate through each submitted file item to check if it's valid or not.

Comment: Would this be the correct way to do it? `!($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][0]) && $_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'] != 4)`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I tried this, but no luck. `if (!$_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][0] && $_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'] != 4) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the issue resides in how you are checking the file(s).

Something along the lines of this below should work, without having to redo your code or implement "advanced" error handling.

Using a custom $_FILES array I built based on what your dump looks like, factoring both the "multiple files are multiple arrays" and the "multiple files are nested under 'uploadedFile'" methods, and they both work.

## Method 1

```
$_FILES = array(
    'uploadedFile' => array(
        'name' => array(0 => ""), 
        'error' => array(0 => 2)
    ),
    'uploadedFile2' => array(
        'name' => array(0 => "aasd"), 
        'error' => array(0 => 4)
    ),
    'uploadedFile3' => array(
        'name' => array(0 => ""), 
        'error' => array(0 => 4)
    )
);
```

[Method #1 working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgFNU.png)

## Method 2

```
$_FILES = array(
    'uploadedFile' => array(
        'name' => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "aasd",
            2 => ""
        ), 
        'error' => array(
            0 => 2,
            1 => 4,
            2 => 4
        )
        //...
    )
);
```

[Method #2 working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE2fM.png)

```
<?php
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    foreach($file['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value != null) { //non-empty string
            if($file['error'][$key] != 4) { //error code is not #4
                die ("name is NOT empty AND error is NOT 4");
            } else { //error code IS #4
                die("error code is 4");
            }
        } else {
            die("name is EMPTY!");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: No matter if I put my code where you say to or in the last else statement (Where I think it should be because the name would not be empty and file should be uploaded then, it still runs all the time.

Comment: Are you submitting the form naturally (within the <form>)? Or with JavaScript?

Comment: Ajax submission.

Comment: Try my edited version above, does it output anything?  One of those die()'s should catch it.

Comment: The else statement with this echo `error code is 4` is outputting. However, the else under it is running because my $out message is being included in the email I receive. I just updated my question with the code I have.

Comment: @Paul, the updated version of my code above changes `if($value == "")` to `if($value != null)`, have you tried that? I did not realize something in your original code that led me to make that mistake originally.

Comment: That still didn't help. With zero attachments, I still get the "Name is NOT empty" echo outputting.

Comment: @Paul what about changing `if($value != null)` to `if($value != "0")` ? If that does not work, I do not know what will. Maybe try it with and without the quotes, also?

Comment: However, if I upload more than one file, I get this error `PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in` for this line `foreach ($filename as $indFile) {` ... any idea why?

Comment: @Paul, can you show me the result of your var_dump($_FILES) with those multiple files?